# Why plugin terser-webpack-plugin add info about package to minified code?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, minify, package.json

I use react-scripts which use this plugin during bundling to minify code. Code is build by codebuild on aws. Codebuild build always in different directories like /codebuild/output/src031636421 or /codebuild/output/src593949567. When this plugin is used then package info is added to minified code.
It causes that when react-scripts use [contenthash] from webpack in file name, the file name is always different because source code is different.

When I commit this plugin then this info isn't added but code isn't minified.

Is it possible to config this plugin to doesn't add this info to code?

Below is part of minified code after js pretty.

```
e.exports = {
    _args: [
        ["jsdom@15.1.1", "/codebuild/output/src031636421"]
    ],
    _dependenciesComments: {
        parse5: "Pinned to exact version number because we monkeypatch its internals (see htmltodom.js)"
    },
    _from: "jsdom@15.1.1",
    _id: "jsdom@15.1.1",
    _inBundle: !1,
    _location: "/jsdom",
    _phantomChildren: {
        "ip-regex": "2.1.0",
        psl: "1.1.32",
        punycode: "2.1.1"
    },

    _requested: {
        type: "version",
        registry: !0,
        raw: "jsdom@15.1.1",
        name: "jsdom",
        escapedName: "jsdom",
        rawSpec: "15.1.1",
        saveSpec: null,
        fetchSpec: "15.1.1"
    },
    _requiredBy: ["/"],
    _resolved: "https://registry.npmjs.org/jsdom/-/jsdom-15.1.1.tgz",
    _spec: "15.1.1",
    _where: "/codebuild/output/src031636421",
    browser: {
        canvas: !1,
        vm: "./lib/jsdom/vm-shim.js",
        "./lib/jsdom/living/websockets/WebSocket-impl.js": "./lib/jsdom/living/websockets/WebSocket-impl-browser.js"
    },

    bugs: {
        url: "https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues"
    }
```